# How To Avoid Queries in loops

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi how can i avoid queries like these?

sample query:

```
$sql = DB::getInstance()->prepare("SELECT tb_id1 FROM table1 WHERE duedate < ?");
$sql->execute(array($currentdate));
  if($sql->rowCount()){
     while($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){      

   $sql2 = DB::getInstance()->prepare("UPDATE table2 SET isOverdue = 1 WHERE tb_id2 = ?");
   $sql2->execute(array($row["tb_id1"]));


    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use update with join and thus by not using any loop in PHP

```
update table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t1.tb_id1 = t2.tb_id2
set t2.isOverdue = 1 
where 
t1.duedate < ?
```

Comment: Hi..sorry for late reply.. i tried to update table1 and table 2 using your code. UPDATE table2 t2 JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.tb_id1 = t2.tb_id2 
  SET t2.isOverdue = 1, t2.DateOverdue = ? , t1.isOverdue = 1
  WHERE t1.duedate < ? AND t2.isOpen = 1 AND t2.isClosed = 0   AND t1.isClosed = 0.  and it works fine.. thanks a lot.